# How to get the value from object based array in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In soap web service, how to get the values in user array and store it in different string. I have to store the title, firstname, etc. in `NSString`. How to do this in objective c?

```
   - (IBAction)loginbutton:(id)sender {
   //calling the soap message
    NSString *userid = _username.text;
    NSString *password = _password.text;
   soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my soap url",userid,password];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my soap url"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
    [theRequest addValue:@"www.etownpanchayat.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/LoginDetails" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //initiate the request
    NSURLConnection *connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if(connection)
    {
        webResponseData = [NSMutableData data] ;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection is NULL");
    }
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self.webResponseData  setLength:0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.webResponseData  appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Some error in your Connection. Please try again.");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Received %d Bytes", [webResponseData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:
                        [webResponseData mutableBytes] length:[webResponseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);

    //now parsing the xml

    NSData *myData = [theXML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:myData];

    //setting delegate of XML parser to self
    xmlParser.delegate = self;

    // Run the parser
    @try{
        BOOL parsingResult = [xmlParser parse];
        NSLog(@"parsing result = %hhd",parsingResult);
    }
    @catch (NSException* exception)
    {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Server Error" message:[exception reason] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
}
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:
(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentElement = elementName;
    NSLog(@" %@ the current .......",currentElement);

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"Parsed Element : %@", currentElement);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSArray *)userArray
{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"LoginDetailsResult"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ the out value is ",userArray);
       //In user array i am getting the following response [{"Title":"Mrs","FirstName":"Pavithra","LastName":"(null)","ContactNo":"8073243634","EmailId":"test123456","DoorNo":"","StreetName":"","City":"v","Pincode":"v","State":"b","Country":"v","Address":"vb","UserId":526722}]

        }

}
```

Comment: Lookup NSJSONSerialization. There are *lots* of examples and tutorials.

Comment: It is an array of dictionaries. So you have to do [[array objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Title"]; to get values.

Comment: @MartinR SOAP is XML, not JSON

Comment: @Cœur: My comment referred to the initial revision of the question, which shows some JSON but no code, and does not mention SOAP.

Comment: @Martin R sry for my mistake sir ,i am using the soap webservice and i am not using the json .can u pls update your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create new class named it UserModel inherited from NSObject and write below code in UserModel.h class

```
@interface UserModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* lastName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* contactNo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* emailId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* doorNo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* streetName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* city;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* pincode;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* state;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* country;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* address;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* userId;

- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict;
```

And in the UserModel.m class add this code

```
- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.title = dict[@"Title"];
        self.firstName = dict[@"FirstName"];
        self.lastName = dict[@"LastName"];
        self.contactNo = dict[@"ContactNo"];
        self.emailId = dict[@"EmailId"];
        self.doorNo = dict[@"DoorNo"];
        self.streetName = dict[@"StreetName"];
        self.city = dict[@"City"];
        self.pincode = dict[@"Pincode"];
        self.state = dict[@"State"];
        self.country = dict[@"Country"];
        self.address = dict[@"Address"];
        self.userId = dict[@"UserId"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

import UserModel.h in your class in which you are parsing then in the code where you have received an array of dictionary and take Global(You can also take local depends upon your logic you are applying)

```
#import UserModel.h
UserModel* _userObj

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSArray *)userArray
{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"LoginDetailsResult"])
   {
        NSLog(@"%@ the out value is ",userArray);
       for (NSDictionary* dict in  modelsListArray)
         {
            //UserModel* obj = [[UserModel alloc]  initWithDictionary:dict]; 
            _userObj = [[UserModel alloc]  initWithDictionary:dict]
         }
    }
}
```

Now If you are setting data on UIlabel of UiTextFields user below code for setting data

```
self.firstNameLabel.text = _userObj. firstName;
self.lastNameLabel.text = _userObj. lastName;
```

This is the MVC design pattern. Try to follow this model always.

Comment: thanks for ur reply sir but it throws the 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Comment: Copy your hole jsonData here

Comment: yes, i copied the json data in nsarray .but still showing that error

Comment: What ever you are getting from server just code that on stack over flow in you question

Comment: Wait I will update my answer very soon. I am busy right now

Comment: Sir please update the answer still I am looking the solution for that

Comment: Welcome @pavithra. For any query feel free to contact

Answer (score 0):

I could say that use **model class** for better handling of this kind of data. Create NSObject class, say 'User' and add all these properties to the class. Using any JSON parsers like, SBJSON, convert your response to model class so that you will get an array of model class objects. Then you will be able to handle this response very easily(user.title, user.firstname etc.)

Answer (score -2):

first:the dictionary is write wrong
u can try this:

NSArray * array = @[@{@"Title":@"Mrs",@"UserId":@526722}]; NSLog(@"%@",array); hope can help u;

Comment: thanks for your reply have to take the array object value i don't need to print the entire array.

Comment: NSLog(@"Title   =   %@,UserId = %@",array[0][@"Title"],array[0][@"UserId"]);
u can try this